# edit search result on PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to allow admin side of my website to edit member detail.

I have created search for admin so s/he can search users via their name or surname,
and I want to have edit link for each search result that it will come back.

just to let you know I really don't know how to do it.
This is the code I have

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>search</title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function serachq ()
        {
            var searchTxt= $("input[name='search']").val();

            $.post("search.php", {searchVal: searchTxt}, function(output){
                $("#output").html(output);      
            });   
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="index.php" method="post"> 
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="search for members..." onkeydown="serachq();"/>
        <input type="submit" value=">>" />
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div id="output">
        </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

and this is PHP code

```
<?php require_once("db_connection.php"); ?>
<?php 
    $output="";
    if (isset($_POST['searchVal']))
    {
        $searchq=$_POST['searchVal'];
        $searchq= preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
        $query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member WHERE first_name LIKE '%$searchq%' OR last_name LIKE'%$searchq%'") or die ("could not search");
        $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if($count == 0){
            $output="there was no serach results!";
        }
        else 
        {
            while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
            {
                $fname=$row ['first_name'];
                $lname=$row['last_name'];
                $id= $row['member_id'];
                $output.='<div>'.$fname.' '.$lname.' '.$id.'<a href="add-member.php?edit=<?php echo $query ['$id']; ?>">Edit Subject</a> </div>';
            }
        }    
    }
    echo ($output);
?>
```

Comment: So what's your question? Also on SO we don't do your code

Comment: ..."so can you please help me ?"  Ask a more concise question would be my advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really you need to write the question's better in the future.  Specifically, if you are getting an error provide the error.  If you expect a certian result, tell us what you get instead.  That said the thing that stands out is:

```
<?php echo $query ['$id'];
```

Where I imagine you meant:

```
<?php echo $query[$id];
```

Here is that part of the code cleaned up:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
{
    $fname = $row['first_name'];
    $lname = $row['last_name'];
    $id = $row['member_id'];
    $output .= "<div>{$fname} {$lname} {$id} <a href=\"add-member.php?edit={$query[$id]}\">Edit Subject</a></div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question properly, you can do using session, put `$searchq` in session and when you come back you can make the query form session

```
      if (isset($_POST['searchVal']) || isset($_SESSION['serachq'])) {
            if (isset($_POST['searchVal'])) {
                $searchq = $_POST['searchVal'];
                $_SESSION['serachq'] = $searchq;
            } else {
                $searchq = $_SESSION['serachq'];
            }
        }
```

or you can modify your link `add-member.php?edit=<?php echo $query ['$id']; ?>&q=<?php echo urlencode()?>`

and your back url should have the `&q=<?php echo urlencode()?>` part too then

```
       if (isset($_POST['searchVal']) || isset($_GET['q'])) {
            if (isset($_POST['searchVal'])) {
                $searchq = $_POST['searchVal'];
            } else {
                $searchq = urldecode($_GET['q']);
            }
        }
```

`